# how to integrate Paypal payment in e commerce website

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

i have made a bookstore website. My all work is completed . Now i am stuck in "Payment" part.
I have to implement Paypal payment exactly like [this website.](http://www.mandalabookpoint.com/index.php)

I read the Paypal developer page. But exactly i could not found any correct documentation to implement Paypal payment.

i have made my own shopping cart. If users click on checkout then they should be forwarded to Paypal for payment.

Please help me by giving me few suggestion regarding the payment integration similar to the above mention link.

Comment: Maybe you should do a bit more research before asking a question... https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-how-to-guides

Comment: i did research from last 3 days. But could not found the exact documentation to implement this. I was confused with many documentation. Then finally i am asking your help. I want to make payment similar like the above mention link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The site you have shown is using Express Checkout method. You can find the documentation here https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted

There is another method the "Adaptive Payment" but this one is quite complicated. I do suggest use Express Checkout instead.

**Updated**

You can include user define variable in your header request for payment to PayPal then all transaction details can be received via IPN or Instant Payment Notification after successful payment. The details you need are there in this IPN. To implement IPN make sure you have followed the following requirements.

1. Your IPN handler URL should be public and no authentication. This is
   the URL that PayPal will be called to send the IPN details.
2. Your handler should have HTTP Post. You can access the IPN message
   through Request.Forms

Comment: i have made my own shopping cart. When users click on the checkout button. Then they will be ask to signup/sign In/Enter details as visitor. if they  submit the any one of this form . Then they will be proceeded for the Paypal payment . After their successful payment through Paypal, They will be redirected  to my success page,in my success page i want the bookid & userid to be return. So that i can save them into my db as payment info.  IS THIS POSSIBLE TO DO? If so then please give me some hint. I am very struggling with this

Comment: you said `include user define variable in your header request for payment to PayPal` what does it mean in detail? what type of variable i will define? any example

Comment: for example the one you said bookid & userid. you can include that.